# smart class to val property inside the class

Tags: kotlin

public val properties for interface does't do smart casting to the object that were set into them. 
is there an alternative?

There is an option do declare 2 variables. one public interface and one private instance. but I prefer just one

what I wish to have:

```
class MyClass{
    val myObservable: Observable<Unit> = PublishSubject.create<Unit>()

    fun foo(){
        myObservable.onNext(Unit) // smart casting doesn't work
    }
}
```

what works but involves boilerplate code

```
class MyClass{
    private val myPublisher = PublishSubject.create<Unit>()
    val myObservable: Observable<Unit> = myPublisher

    fun foo(){
        myPublisher.onNext(Unit)
    }
}
```

Comment: Course not. `Observable<Unit>` does not have `onNext`. The second one is correct.

Comment: It does look to me like adding smart cast for this would make sense. You may want to suggest it on https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/.